# Optimization of a black-box function made of step-functions

Tags: optimization

I need to optimize a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ of which the explicit form  missing, but I can evaluate it at any point of its domain. The only thing I know is that such function is piecewise constant. Also, the evaluation of the function is time-consuming, so is preferable that the set of points at which the function is evaluated remains relatively small.

I wanted to use some kind of direct search method, but it looks like the latter do not converge for non-differentiable function.

Is there any other method which can be used to optimize a black-box function made of step functions? Alternatively, is there any argument I can use in order to legitimate the use of a direct search algorithm although it does not converge?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Surely you know a little more about your function. Otherwise, I would say that it looks quite hopeless. Being a step function gives you almost no information.

Let us take $n=1$, and even imagine that your function is only defined on $[0,1]$ (not the full real line $\mathbb{R}$), so that the domain in which we are searching for is bounded. Let us also imagine that you *know* that your function has exactly $10$ steps, located on $[\frac {j-1}{10}, \frac{j}{10}]$ for $j \in \{ 1, \dotsc, 10 \}$. So your function is characterized by its $10$ values on these $10$ steps. If you have no *a priori* information on these values, then there is no better algorithm then to compute the ten values by evaluating $f$ say at the middle of each of these steps.

You **have** to add some kind of (even implicit) assumption on the behavior of the function or its steps to be able to use a more clever algorithm. Otherwise, as we have seen, the values could be completely random, even if we have *a priori* knowledge of the number of steps and their position.